# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined when returning nested promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I keep getting the following error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined**, in checkInventoryData. How can I resolve it?

```
function checkInventoryData(url, size, code) {
  var inventoryData = { };

  return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
    var html = response.data;

    // getting error here: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    getInventoryProductQty(html, size).then(function(result) {
        result = inventoryData.productQty;
    });

    return inventoryData;
  });
}

function getInventoryProductQty(html, size) {
  var inventoryAvailable;
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  try {
    var inventoryAvailablity = getInventoryAvailability(html, size);
    inventoryAvailablity.then(function(result) {
      if(result) {
        inventoryAvailable = result.getAttribute('data-available');
        deferred.resolve(inventoryAvailable);
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    });
  }
  catch(err) {
    inventoryAvailable = null;
    return inventoryAvailable;
  }
}
```

Comment: as an aside, unrelated to my answer, there is no need to set inventoryAvailable to null before returning it, you can just return null, and instead of assigning `var inventoryAvailability = getInventoryAvailability(html, size)`, you can just chain off of the function call on the next line

Comment: You have a lot more issues with this code... once the `then` issue is fixed, `checkInventoryData` will always return an empty object.

Comment: @trincot how do I fix both issues? Would really appreciate your help

Comment: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a promise from `getInventoryProductQty`, right now you return null in the error case, but nothing in the normal case (and neither of those are promises.

**EDIT** - showing this answer in OPs code, and comment on the structure.

```
function checkInventoryData(url, size, code) {
  var inventoryData = { };

  return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
    var html = response.data;

    // getting error here: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    getInventoryProductQty(html, size).then(function(result) {
        result = inventoryData.productQty; // this has not been set at this point, you need to set it somehow (@trincot's comment)
    });

    return inventoryData;
  });
}

function getInventoryProductQty(html, size) {
  var inventoryAvailable;
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  try {
    var inventoryAvailablity = getInventoryAvailability(html, size);
    return inventoryAvailablity.then(function(result) { // need to add this return to return the result of the then func
      if(result) {
        inventoryAvailable = result.getAttribute('data-available');
        deferred.resolve(inventoryAvailable);
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    });
  }
  catch(err) {
    //inventoryAvailable = null;
    //return inventoryAvailable;
    return $q.resolve(null); // need something like this to return a promise from the failure case
  }
}
```

You also should make `getInventoryAvailability` return a promise so that it can be called with a `.catch` instead of a `try...catch`, but that's beyond the scope of this

Comment: I thought that `return deferred.promise;` was the promise being returned?

Comment: It would be, but you aren't. You are returning `deferred.promise` from within the then in the try branch, but nothing from the top level function

Comment: this statement is within a `then` so it only resolves this promise. But nothing is returned outside.

Comment: what you probably want to do is `return inventoryAvailablity.then` instead. But take care of your `catch` which does not return a promise, as @methuselah pointed out.

Comment: @ValLeNain can you please show me an example of how this would look?

Comment: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: @Bergi didn't know it had a name, but that's where I was heading with the last line

Comment: @JimDeville struggling to get `inventoryData`: http://pastebin.com/Lus2wnes at the moment, how would I refactor this?

Comment: Not sure what the problem with that is

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing for now, inside `getInventoryProductQty`

```
inventoryAvailablity.then(function(result) {
      if(result) {
        inventoryAvailable = result.getAttribute('data-available');
        deferred.resolve(inventoryAvailable);
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    });
```

This is not a return statement and so your function does not return anything.
If what you would like to return is `inventoryAvailable` (once it has been retrieved), you would do something like

```
return inventoryAvailablity.then(function(result) {
  if(result) {
    inventoryAvailable = result.getAttribute('data-available');
    return inventoryAvailable;
  } else {
    /* reject ? */
  }
});
```

[edit]
I would actually rewrite the function this way

```
function getInventoryProductQty(html, size) {
  var inventoryAvailable;
  try {
    var inventoryAvailablity = getInventoryAvailability(html, size);
    return inventoryAvailablity.then(function(result) {
      if(result) {
        inventoryAvailable = result.getAttribute('data-available');
        return inventoryAvailable;
      } else {
        /* reject ? */
      }
    });
  }
  catch(err) {
    return $q.reject(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you rely on a promise, you need to make sure to keep returning promises in the call chain.

Here is the suggested code:

```
function checkInventoryData(url, size, code) {
  // Warning: code is nowhere used!
  // Return(!) the promise:
  return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
    var html = response.data;
    return getInventoryProductQty(html, size);
  });
}

function getInventoryProductQty(html, size) {
  try {
    // return the result of `then`, which is a promise:
    return getInventoryAvailability(html, size).then(function(result) {
      if(result) {
        // Just return the value. No need to return a promise.
        // I assume you have a productQty property here:
        return result.getAttribute('data-available').productQty;
      } else { // also deal with the failure:
        throw "no result from getInventoryAvailability";
      }
    });
  }
  catch(err) {
    // return a failed promise here:
    return $q.reject(err);
  }
}
```

Don't expect `checkInventoryData` to synchronously return the value. It is also a promise, and you need to apply `then` to it to get the promised value in a callback function. Also make sure to use a `catch` method whenever you call `checkInventoryData`, so you can deal with errors.

Comment: Given that `getInventoryAvailability` never throws, that `try`/`catch` is pretty useless

Comment: That is indeed true if `getInventoryAvailability` can be trusted to return a promise. But OP did not provide the code for it.